# How do I make a paging Stored Procedure in SQL Server dynamic, able to be used for more than one dataset?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, pagination

From,

https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2314819&seqNum=2

> ```
> ALTER PROC dbo.GetPage
>   @pagenum  AS BIGINT = 1,
>   @pagesize AS BIGINT = 25
> AS
>
> WITH C AS
> (
>   SELECT orderid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY orderid) AS rn
>   FROM dbo.Orders
> ),
> K AS
> (
>   SELECT orderid, rn
>   FROM C
>   WHERE rn BETWEEN (@pagenum - 1) * @pagesize + 1 AND @pagenum * @pagesize
> )
> SELECT O.orderid, O.orderdate, O.custid, O.empid
> FROM dbo.Orders AS O
>   INNER JOIN K
>     ON O.orderid = K.orderid
> ORDER BY K.rn;
> GO
> ```
>
> Run the procedure again requesting the third page:
>
> ```
> EXEC dbo.GetPage @pagenum = 3, @pagesize = 25;
> ```

How do I make this dynamic so that I can use any dataset for my database?  I have it working in my application, but what if, for example, I want to return the pages for a person's lastname I did with a `LIKE`?  I don't think it is correct to write a new paging SP for each query I have.

Comment: The paging portion of these isn't very complicated. And yes it would require a custom one for each dataset. Notice that you are using ROW_NUMBER in your Orders table.

Comment: @SeanLange I found lots of ways to paginate, and this was one example, but it seemed odd to do one for each query.  That's too bad.

Comment: @SeanLange Is there any reason I should not send my SQL with the OFFSET and FETCH like I would any other query that is not a SP?  At least then I could have a class that is dynamic.